# Como retirar os espaços em branco de um texto?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Eu estava tentando tirar espaços em branco de uma *string*, mas o `.Trim()` não funciona, isso exibe os espaços em branco ainda:

```
 var teste = texto.Trim();
 txtConteudo.Text = teste;
```

Por exemplo, se ele receber: " texto texto ", continua: "texto texto" mesmo depois de passar pelo `Trim`. Ele não deveria mostrar "textotexto"? Como obter este resultado?

Comment: Porque não funciona? Mostre, dê detalhes. Funcionando: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kaKhfO

Comment: ele mostra na textBox o texto com espaços... Editei a pergunta!

Comment: Como você sabe? Coloque uma cópia da tela **mostrando** que tem os espaços. Talvez o problema esteja em outro lugar.

Comment: Você pergunta por que o `Trim` não funciona para remover espaço do começo da string mas no código você estava usando `TrimEnd`. Ou seja, o problema era apenas um erro de digitação?

Comment: não, o problema era como eu estava pensando que o Trim funcionava...

Comment: O @Caffé tem razão. O título da pergunta não bate com o código apresentado - se batesse, os espaços em branco teriam sido removidos. Claramente foi um erro de digitação e a pergunta deve ser encerrada.

Comment: @dcastro Editei a pergunta, eu tinha colocado o trimEnd na pergunta por engano, mas expliquei ali o problema

Comment: A pergunta não é um erro de digitação, é o desconhecimento sobre o recurso a ser usado para obter o que desejava.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Existem 3 métodos para cortar espaços, pode cortar no início, no fim, ou ambos. Tem que usar o correto para o que deseja. Ainda é possível cortar todos. O exemplo mostrado na pergunta indica o uso do método errado:

```
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var texto = " Hello World ";
        WriteLine($"Corta o fim: |{texto.TrimEnd()}|");
        WriteLine($"Corta o início: |{texto.TrimStart()}|");
        WriteLine($"Corta ambos: |{texto.Trim()}|");
        WriteLine($"Corta tudo: |{texto.Replace(" ", "")}|");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FSpKBG). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FAbj5E). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Trim.cs).

- [`Trim()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads)
- [`TrimStart()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_TrimStart_System_Char___)
- [`TrimEnd()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_TrimEnd_System_Char___)
- [`Replace()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: seu ligeiro. Faço mais perguntas do que respondo, pois quando vou responder já era (quem manda eu ser lento). Brincadeiras a parte, +1 pela resposta.

Comment: @bigown, o que significa esse "$" antes da String?

Comment: Eu estava usando o Trim de forma errada, eu achava que ele tbm fazia o que o replace faz, obrigado pelo esclarecimento!

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates abre uma pergunta que eu respondo :D Vai ser útil para todo mundo.

Comment: @bigown, abrirei já!

Answer (score 3):

A função Trim apenas remove os espaços em branco que estão contidos no início e fim da string, ou seja os espaços em branco que venha a existir por dentro da string não seram removidos.

```
var texto = " Texto a ser removidos seus espaços. ";

//Trim() remove os espaços do inícil e do fim da string.
var trimTexto = texto.Trim();//Output: "Texto a ser removidos seus espaços."

//TrimStart() remove os espaços somente do inícil da string.
var trimTexto2 = texto.TrimStart();//Output: "Texto a ser removidos seus espaços. "

//TrimEnd() remove os espaços somente do fim da string.
var trimTexto3 = texto.TrimEnd();//Output: " Texto a ser removidos seus espaços."
```

Answer (score -3):

```
function getCdEspacosRetirar($valor){ 
    $array  = explode(" ", $valor);
    $valor  =   '';
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($array); $i++) { $valor    .= ($array[$i])? 
$array[$i].' ':'';}
return trim($valor);}

$nomeAdmin  =   ' wanderley           ricardo          de                 
araujo  ';
$nomeAdmin  =   getCdEspacosRetirar($nomeAdmin);
```

Deve existir funções similares em outra linguagem. Essa é php.

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta o fulcro é C#.